# Prove that the wheel $W_7$ is not decomposable into two isomorphic subgraphs.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that the wheel $W_7$ is not decomposable into two isomorphic subgraphs.

I wanted to show by stating that odd number of edges cannot be divided by 2 but I found wheel 7 has even number of edges so I have no idea how to start.[image]

Comment: **Hint:** There is only one vertex of degree $7$ in the graph $W_7$

Comment: A moment's consideration shows that the wheel on $7$ vertices is indeed decomposable into two isomorphic subgraphs, so apparently $W_7$ means the wheel on $8$ vertices in this case. Therefore I suggest that @PrasunBiswas expands his comment to an answer, and either OP or Prasun edits the question for clarity. No need for any more details; it seems to me that the hint is a fine answer as it is.

Comment: I have edited the question. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: So the proof is because there is only 1 vertex of degree 7, if this vertex is contained in one subgraph, then there is no corresponding vertex of degree 7 in the other subgraph; if the edges incident with this vertex of degree 7 are decomposed into 2 subgraphs, there is one vertex of degree 4 in only one subgraph. Am I right?

Comment: Well, yes. Except that you only know that there will be a vertex of degree *at least* 4 in one of the subgraphs, not necessarily exactly 4. Well done!

Comment: @jiqiudabao Close. "This vertex is contained in one subgraph" is meaningless: the subgraphs we're talking about are spanning subgraphs, each of them contains all the vertices. The point is that there is one vertex of degree $7$ and all other vertices have degree $3.$ Thus, if we decompose the wheel into two subgraphs, one and only one of them will have a vertex of degree greater than $3.$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, if you don't write up your answer then I'll have to make a community wiki answer, which doesn't give you any credit. No pressure. ;-)

Comment: Now I totally understand. Thanks all for your help! Really appreciate!

Answer (score 1):

Two graphs that are isomorphic must have a matching [degree sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)#Degree_sequence) (although a matching degree sequence is not a guarantee of isomorphism). In particular the maximum degree of both needs to be the same.

In the case of your graph shown, the central vertex must correspond a vertex of degree at least $4$ in one of the two decomposition parts and $3$ or less in the other. Since all other vertices are degree $3$, the maximum degree cannot be the same in both parts and thus they are not isomorphic.

The number of edges being $14$, the only other non-trivial decomposition which might produce all isomorphic graphs is that into $7$ parts, which is indeed simple to achieve.